# Having issue with blog page sidebar

Tags: wordpress, blogs, sidebar, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a website in WordPress.In the blog page I have a sidebar.I did add some widgets there but the option in the widgets are not clicable.How can I make them Clickable.
Link:http://workwithmaxmarketer.com/blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class **`widget-area`** is overlapping the sidebar.

I have two solutions here.

First (i recommend), From your CSS style, add this code below:

```
.widget-area:before{
   z-index:-1 !important;
}
```

or

Second (not recommended), from http://workwithmaxmarketer.com/wp-content/themes/betheme/css/layout.css?ver=11.8

remove position: absolute; from property .widget-area:before

Cheers,